# find connected components of filtered graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

How can I calculate the connected components of a filtered graph using BGL?  I've created a working filter that checks against a custom vertex property called "alive" and returns only the "living" vertices but `connected_components` chokes on the `filtered_graph` .  I think it has something to do with the fact that the filtered graph has non-contiguous vertex ids and therefore an `operator[]` that was defined is now no longer defined but I'm not sure why or how to code around it.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties> Graph;
typedef boost::property_map<Graph, ::vertex_alive_t>::type AliveMap;

template <typename AliveMap>
struct vertex_is_alive {
  vertex_is_alive() { }
  vertex_is_alive(AliveMap alive) : m_alive(alive) { }
  template <typename Vertex>
  bool operator()(const Vertex& v) const {
    return boost::get(m_alive,v) == STILL_ALIVE_CODE;
  }
  AliveMap m_alive;
};

Graph G;
//generate G...
int N = boost::num_vertices(G);
vector<int> component(N);
int num = boost::connected_components(G, &component[0]);
//do something with component and play around with vertex_alive statuses...this part works fine.
vertex_is_alive<AliveMap> filter(boost::get(::vertex_alive_t(), G));
boost::filtered_graph<Graph, vertex_is_alive<AliveMap> > fG (G, filter); 
int num = boost::connected_components(fG, &component[0]);
//this makes it choke
```

The error messages that I get are (removing the genealogy):

```
/usr/local/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:354:56: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘((const boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<vertex_alive_t, unsigned int> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<vertex_alive_t, unsigned int> >*, unsigned int, unsigned int&, vertex_alive_t>&)pa)[k]’
/usr/local/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:354:56: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:245:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2465:24: note: Reference boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map<Graph, GraphPtr, ValueType, Reference, Tag>::operator[](boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map<Graph, GraphPtr, ValueType, Reference, Tag>::key_type) const [with Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<vertex_alive_t, unsigned int> >; GraphPtr = boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<vertex_alive_t, unsigned int> >*; ValueType = unsigned int; Reference = unsigned int&; Tag = vertex_alive_t; boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map<Graph, GraphPtr, ValueType, Reference, Tag>::key_type = unsigned int]
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2465:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, unsigned int>’ to ‘boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<vertex_alive_t, unsigned int> >, boost::adjacency_list<boost::hash_mapS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::property<vertex_alive_t, unsigned int> >*, unsigned int, unsigned int&, vertex_alive_t>::key_type {aka unsigned int}’
```

Comment: You should use `boost::filtered_graph<Graph,boost::keep_all, vertex_is_alive<AliveMap> > fG (G, boost::keep_all(), filter);`. The signature for the filtered graph is `
filtered_graph<Graph, EdgePredicate, VertexPredicate>` so you were using your vertex filter as an edge one. The last line in your error implies that `boost::get(m_alive,x)` requires that x be a vertex descriptor (unsigned int) and it was being passed an edge descriptor (const boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, unsigned int>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use boost::filtered_graph > fG (G, boost::keep_all(), filter);. The signature for the filtered graph is `filtered_graph<Graph, EdgePredicate, VertexPredicate>` so you were using your vertex filter as an edge one. The last line in your error implies that boost::get(m_alive,x) requires that x be a vertex descriptor (`unsigned int`) and it was being passed an edge descriptor (`const boost::detail::edge_desc_impl<boost::undirected_tag, unsigned int>`).